# My website form fields are hiding behind the keyboard in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing a website. Sort of a plugin. It has a login page. When I click username or password, the body of website should compress. But instead it hides behind the keyboard. I am using bootstrap inside it. I tried to implement this script in the header of page but this is not working. Any tips?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').blur(function() {
        $('body').css({'height':'100vh'})
      })
      .focus(function() {
        $('body').css({'height':'50vh'})
      });
  });
```

Comment: When the keyboard appears you should be able to scroll your page to access the page elements that are now behind the keyboard. Is that not the case?

Comment: This should be the case but this does not happen. IDK why.